# Where can I find an online copy of ספר החכמה?

Tags: product-recommendation, jewish-books, internet, rishonim

In Gittin 10b, many Rishonim (Mordechai [who appears to have been a student of his] and a few more) reference one רבינו יקיר (aka אפרים, as in "הבן יקיר לי אפרים"), in a work called ספר החכמה. I can't seem to find a copy anywhere, and was wondering if there is an online copy of the work available.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [Encyclopedi Yehudit](http://www.daat.ac.il/encyclopedia/value.asp?id1=2009) ר' ברוך בר' שמואל ממגנצא' was the author of Sefer Hachachma and it has been lost.

> ברוך בן שמואל ממגנצא - תלמודי ופייטן. חי בסוף המאה הי"ב ומת במגנצא
>   בשנת 1221. היה תלמיד מובהק של רבי אליעזר ממיץ. חתם על התקנות שנעשו
>   במגנצא בשנת ד"א תתק"ף המובאות בסוף מהר"ם דפוס פראג.
>
> חיבר את ספר "החכמה" בהלכה המובא בראשונים, הספר היה בכ"י אצל ר' בצלאל
>   אשכנזי שהעתיק ממנו את כללי התלמוד שלו, והוזכר בשיטה מקובצת לכתובות
>   ל"ד: ולב"מ ס"ח. ע"ח:. כנראה שאבד.

According to הבלעת דם (in the note on the bottom of [this page](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=6800&st=&pgnum=43&hilite=)), ר' ברוך בר' שמואל ממגנצא (author of ספר החכמה) was the student of רבינו (אפרים) יקיר.